# What is considered a good response time for a dynamic, personalized web application?

Tags: performance, scalability

For a complex web application that includes dynamic content and personalization, what is a good response time from the server (so excluding network latency and browser rendering time)?  I'm thinking about sites like Facebook, Amazon, MyYahoo, etc.  A related question is what is a good response time for a backend service?

Comment: For a site such as Facebook, they have a 1.8-2 second time to first byte / which includes a good chunk of content on page.  Then they ajax the rest of the content in the next 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 200):

There's a great deal of research on this. Here's a [quick summary](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html).

> ### Response Times: The 3 Important Limits
>
> by [Jakob Nielsen](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/author/jakob-nielsen/) on January 1, 1993
>
> Summary: There are 3 main time limits (which are determined by human perceptual abilities) to keep in mind when optimizing web and application performance.
>
> *Excerpt from Chapter 5 in my book [Usability Engineering](http://www.nngroup.com/books/usability-engineering/), from 1993:*
>
> The basic advice regarding response times has been about the same for thirty years [Miller 1968; Card et al. 1991]:
>
> - **0.1 second** is about the limit for having the user feel that the system is **reacting instantaneously**, meaning that no special feedback is necessary except to display the result.
> - **1.0 second** is about the limit for the **user's flow of thought** to stay uninterrupted, even though the user will notice the delay. Normally, no special feedback is necessary during delays of more than 0.1 but less than 1.0 second, but the user does lose the feeling of operating directly on the data.
> - **10 seconds** is about the limit for **keeping the user's attention** focused on the dialogue. For longer delays, users will want to perform other tasks while waiting for the computer to finish, so they should be given feedback indicating when the computer expects to be done. Feedback during the delay is especially important if the response time is likely to be highly variable, since users will then not know what to expect.

Comment: Does this still holds good in 2017 ??

Comment: @KarthikCherukuri - yes, it's still relevant. The answer is talking about human perception, which is a function of biology. The time between 1993 and today is pretty small when it comes to evolutionary time scales. Our neuroanatomy is the same now as it was then.

Comment: The first link does not work anymore

Comment: In this age of fully matured social media that brazenly leverages instantaneous feedback looks and endless content feeds, I'm sure these numbers are lower but personally I think these are still good metrics to keep in mind. .1s is never going to change, as its too unnoticeable to the lay person. 1s is likely fine, as people are used to that in today's web as they wait for content to be served. But I fear the gap to "keeping attention" is far lower than 10s. In any case, definitely a +1 here for coming equipped with research and proper citations!

Answer (score 17):

We strive for response times of 20 milliseconds, while some complex pages take up to 100 milliseconds. For the most complex pages, we break the page down into smaller pieces, and use the progressive display pattern to load each section. This way, some portions load quickly, even if the page takes 1 to 2 seconds to load, keeping the user engaged while the rest of the page is loading.

Comment: Maybe 2000 milliseconds and 10000 ms?

Comment: Maybe he really meant 20 milliseconds.  The app I'm presently working on has typical response times averaging around 15 ms (when testing locally on my laptop).  That's not what most users actually see, unfortunately, since they're far away from the server, plus there's render time you have to include, too.  But from a pure app perspective, 15, or even a tad under 10, is very possible, even for a complex e-commerce app.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what keeps your users happy. For example, Gmail takes quite a while to open at first, but users wait because it is worth waiting for.

Comment: That's fair.  My question is a bit general.  I guess I am looking for real world numbers of what people are striving for.  A know a lot of it depends on the situation.  Thanks!

Comment: The faster, the better.

Answer (score 8):

I have been striving for < 3 seconds for my applications, but I'm a bit picky when it comes to performance.

If you ask around, they say that people start to lose interest in the >= 7 second range, by 10-15 seconds you have typically lost them, unless you REALLY have something they want or need.

Comment: 3 seconds for app server or rendering on the browser?  I aim for 100mSec for app server.  but 4 second on the browser.

Comment: < 3 sounds more like you're talking about page load time which is not the same as response time.

Comment: "I have been striving for < 3 seconds [response time] for my applications, but I'm a bit picky when it comes to performance." - was that a joke or have applications improved that much since 2008?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, it lays in the nature of your question, so answers are highly subjective.

The first response of a website is also only a small part of the time until a page is readable/usable.

I am annoyed by everything larger than 10 sec responses. I think a website should be rendered after 5-7 sec.

Btw: stackoverflow.com has an excellent response time!

Answer (score 4):

Our company has a 5 second response time standard limit, and we aim for 2-3 seconds in general. This accounts for 98% of page loads. A few particular tasks are allowed to go up to 15 seconds, but we then mitigate that time by putting up a page and refreshing every 5 seconds telling the user that we are still trying to process the request. That way the user sees that something is happening and doesn't just leave. Although, considering that I work on a website whose users are forced to use for business reasons, they aren't going to leave, but they are capable of complaining quite loudly.

In general, if the processing is going to take more than 5 seconds, put up a temporary page so that the user doesn't lose interest.

Comment: Hi @Elie, I wonder if you still work for that company and if the response time have changed over 14 years now ;) Came here as my request to get paginated list of 24 products takes ~650 ms ( out of 1800 products available )

Answer (score 3):

I think you will find that if your web app is performing a complex operation then provided feedback is given to the user, they won't mind (too much).

For example: Loading Google Mail.

Answer (score 2):

Not only does it depend on what keeps your users happy, but how much development time do you have? What kind of resources can you throw at the problem (software, hardware, and people)?

I don't mind a couple-few second delay for hosted applications if they're doing something "complex". If it's really simple, delays bother me.

Answer (score -10):

2 to 3 seconds